# Screen Tearing in games after shifting to Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, screen, framerate

It's been one month since I'm using Ubuntu and I've noticed some screen tearing in some of games I play, such as CS and I limit FPS to 75 hz because my Monitor is 85 hz.

Now when I'm playing I get 75 fps but I'm experiencing weird screen tearing

I use the Nvidia driver and my GPU is a 750 TI

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Version 340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nvidia 340 driver is out dated, use 346, works great for me, change it in `additional drivers` or

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-340
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

Still got tearing ?

Go to the Nvidia settings, and choose `openGL settings` and check `sync to vblank` this is hardware enabled v-sync and should force v-sync on your game.

Comment: TY :D ill try now

Comment: Now i cant login into Ubuntu after restart HELP !!

Comment: Did the driver install ? Press ctrl+alt+F1, log in, remove the driver - `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340-updates` Now reboot `sudo reboot` and you should have `nvidia-340` back, now use `additional drivers` to install the latest `proprietary` version.

Comment: Done ty :D Working now